# Copy image to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

Seemingly, you can't (yet) programmatically copy an image to the clipboard from a JavaScript web app?

I have tried to copy a text in clipboard , and it's worked.

Now I would like to copy an image and after I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste into Word or Excel or Paint.

```
$(function() { 
    $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#container1"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;

                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
                $("#img-out").append(canvas);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The following might be useful as a relatively reliable/portable (though with added interaction cost) solution: spawn a new tab containing the contents of `theCanvas.toDataURL()`. Then the user can right-click that and "Copy Image" to clipboard.

Comment: Earlier duplicate question: [Copy Image to Clipboard from Browser in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321606/copy-image-to-clipboard-from-browser-in-javascript)

Answer (score 39):

For those still looking, the ClipboardAPI now works with png images.

```
try {
    navigator.clipboard.write([
        new ClipboardItem({
            'image/png': pngImageBlob
        })
    ]);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

Comment: Only works for secure https connections. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805395/navigator-clipboard-is-undefined

Comment: I get the error 'ClipboardItem' is not defined! Can I import this from somewhere?

Comment: It is not supported in Firefox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardItem#browser_compatibility

Comment: you can get a blob from canvas.toBlob( (blob)=>{} );

Comment: @jonas prefix with window. so you are using `window.ClipboardItem`

Comment: best!!!!!! \m/_

Answer (score 32):

This worked across all browsers (as of 2016). I have uploaded on GitHub as well: https://github.com/owaisafaq/copier-js

```js
//Cross-browser function to select content
function SelectText(element) {
  var doc = document;
  if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(element);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(element);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
}
$(".copyable").click(function(e) {
  //Make the container Div contenteditable
  $(this).attr("contenteditable", true);
  //Select the image
  SelectText($(this).get(0));
  //Execute copy Command
  //Note: This will ONLY work directly inside a click listenner
  document.execCommand('copy');
  //Unselect the content
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  //Make the container Div uneditable again
  $(this).removeAttr("contenteditable");
  //Success!!
  alert("image copied!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="copyable">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="Copy Image to Clipboard via Javascript." />
</div>

<div class="copyable">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="Copy Image to Clipboard via Javascript." />
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't add `DataTransferItem` of kind `file` to the `ClipboardEvent` but pure "Copy image" from web browser image context menu does. Basically this code passes images as HTML content instead of pure image.

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox 56, Chrome 61 and Opera 48. Which browser did you use?

Comment: This is really great and very smart idea I tried and it worked for sure.. on chrome 64 and firefox 59 beta.. awesome thinking sir. it does copy the images and you can paste them wherever you want

Comment: However it worth noting that this has it's limitation as czerny said above.. some applications can understand the copied img html others don't.

Comment: Doesn't work in either Firefox Quantum or Chrome (2018)

Comment: See @BasharAliLabadi's comment above.

Comment: Works when I copy from Chrome into Keynote (and presumably other desktop apps), but not when I copy from one Chrome tab into another (i.e., attempting to paste into a browser-based tool like Figma). Does not work in Firefox. Nonetheless, the only working example I was able to find.

Comment: This has become outdated and no longer works, here is the exact copy in codepen - https://codepen.io/mikefreudiger/pen/xMXeoX?editors=1010

Answer (score 9):

So, i created the perfect solution with 1 liner-kinda solution to convert something with html2canvas to a canvas and then produce the image of it and then save it to clipboard as png. For example,

HTML:
`<div id="copyToImage">Hello World!</div>`

JavaScript:

```
$("#copyToImage").click(function() {
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#copyToImage")).then(canvas => canvas.toBlob(blob => navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({'image/png': blob})])));
});
```

Comment: "perfect" does not work in Firefox

Answer (score 6):

You are right. There is no support to copy image data into clipboard in chrome yet. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=150835. 
Looks like it has been open for about 4 years now.

There is a clipboard API spec that is coming up though
https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved by using the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard), which does require that your server is secured. The basic idea is to convert your image to a `blob` before writing it to the clipboard as an image.

```js
const img = document.querySelector("#b64-img");
const copyBtn = document.querySelector("#copy");

copyBtn.onclick = e => {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
      navigator.clipboard.write([
          new ClipboardItem({ "image/png": blob })
      ]);
    }, "image/png");
};
```

```html
<img id="b64-img" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
<br>
<button id="copy">Copy Above Image</button>
```

This will allow you to paste your image to Photoshop and other image-applications.

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox, unfortunately (for most users): ClipboardItem is disabled in Firefox by default. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardItem#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is my first post in here with an answer i guess :)

Actually i'm currently using cefsharp web browser component one of my project, cefsharp run on chrome based browser and i want to copy img element one of webpage

With cefsharp you can manipulate browser only javascript, so i think we can handle it with using canvas element.

```js
/*
  'cause of lorempixel timeout, i used img onload function.
*/

function copyImage() {
  var imgCap = document.getElementById('imgCap');
  var imgCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');

  imgCanvas.id = 'imgCanvas';
  imgCanvas.height = 40;
  imgCanvas.width = 120;

  document.body.appendChild(imgCanvas);
  var originalContext = imgCanvas.getContext('2d');
  originalContext.drawImage(imgCap, 0, 0);

  //return imgCanvas.toDataURL();
}

//document.onload = copyImage();
```

```html
<img id="imgCap" src="http://lorempixel.com/120/40" onload="copyImage();"/>
```

with `return imgCanvas.toDataURL();` you can get base64 encoded value and use wherever you want.

this is my cefsharp code, it's working.

```
        string copyImageOtClipboardScript = "(function(){ try{var imgCap = document.getElementById('imgCap'); var imgCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'); imgCanvas.id = 'imgCanvas'; imgCanvas.height = 40; imgCanvas.width = 120; document.body.appendChild(imgCanvas); var originalContext = imgCanvas.getContext('2d'); originalContext.drawImage(imgCap, 0, 0); return imgCanvas.toDataURL();  }catch(e){ alert(e); } })();";

        var task = chromeBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync(copyImageOtClipboardScript).ContinueWith(x =>
        {
            var resp = x.Result;

            if (resp.Success)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    Bitmap bmp = null;
                    string captchaResult = "", captchaBase64;

                    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(resp.Result.ToString().Replace("data:image/png;base64,", ""));
                    using (var imageFile = new FileStream("temp_captcha.png", FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        imageFile.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        imageFile.Flush();
                    }

                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried the mentioned JavaScript code it's not working.

Comment: @Omar, what did you get ? it is working in code snippet.

Comment: I'm trying the code within the normal standalone Chrome browser (not within a .NET app using CefSharp) .. it seems that your code is intended only to work along with CefSharp within .NET apps. I'm looking for a way to work within the normal daily usage browsers (Chrome, Firefox, …)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this guide to copying and pasting with JavaScript: https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2014/12/02/definitive-guide-copying-pasting-javascript/

According to this, Chrome, Safari, and Firefox all support copying images along with plain text, while IE only allows copying text. The page linked above describes how this service uses an extension to add this functionality to a context menu, but it appears that several browsers support programmatic copying of images.

Comment: There is no support to copy image data into clipboard in chrome yet.  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=150835. Looks like it has been open for about 4 years now.

Comment: Lucid Chart link wasn't working for me, but I found the article here: https://dzone.com/articles/definitive-guide-copying-and

Answer (score 0):

```
const copyImageToClipboard = async () => {
      try {
      await navigator.clipboard.write([
        new ClipboardItem({
          'image/png': await fetch(img).then((r) => r.blob()),
        }),
      ]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

You might run into CORS errors testing on localhost. But you can install a CORS extension to get rid of that issue :)

Answer (score -1):

var image = new Image();

```
        image.src = url;

        copyImageToClipboard(image.src);
```

install it from https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-image-clipboard

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: copyImageToClipboard is not defined` ...

Answer (score -1):

Here is the best  answer i found for you, very simple and its working 100% exactly what you need.

```
await navigator.clipboard.writeText(code);
```

Check out this link: [enter link description here](https://codepen.io/shripalsoni04/pen/wvyWvjJ)

Answer (score -6):

You cannot copy to clip board with Javascript for security reasons, a work around can be found in a discussion here. Involves flash.[Click button copy to clipboard using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery)