# How to put an image to clipboard in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, clipboarddata

How to put image to clipboard using Javascript (in handler of [`copy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/copy) event) as if it would by done by right click on image in browser and selecting "Copy Image" from context menu.

This [script](https://jsfiddle.net/y4p62eoo/) shows details of clipboard content. For copied image it prints:

```
DataTransfer { dropEffect: "none", effectAllowed: "uninitialized", items: DataTransferItemList[2], types: Array[2], files: FileList[1], mozItemCount: 1, mozCursor: "auto", mozUserCancelled: false, mozSourceNode: null }
DataTransferItem { kind: "string", type: "text/html" }
DataTransferItem { kind: "file", type: "image/png" }
Array [ "text/html", "Files" ]
File { name: "image.png", lastModified: 1504122845696, lastModifiedDate: Date 2017-08-30T19:54:05.696Z, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 385273, type: "image/png" }
```

So the question can be probably reformulated - how to attach a file to `clipboardData` in `copy` event handler function?

```js
document.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {
  // event.clipboardData.?
  // maybe event.clipboardData.setData(?)
})
```

Not working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oh3ymnke/3/) using [`setData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData) method.

Comment: Did you search? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33175909/copy-image-to-clipboard

Comment: when you click `copy image` in context menu of right click on the image, its already in clipboard.

Comment: @koushik-chatterjee yes. And I want to simulate such behavior programmatically.

Comment: ok, let me add a answer for working demo

Comment: @epascarello thanks for the link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy image to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33175909/copy-image-to-clipboard)

Answer (score 2):

```js
//get reference to the div
var div = document.getElementById('someDiv');

//attach a paste event
div.addEventListener('paste', function(ev){
    var imgFile = null;
    var idx;
    var items = ev.clipboardData.items;
    for(idx=0;idx<items.length;idx++) {
        //check if any content is file
        if(items[idx].kind==="file") {
            //take that file to imgFile
            imgFile = items[idx].getAsFile();
            break;
        }
    }
    if(imgFile==null) {return;}
    
    //create a File reader
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        //create an img DOM object
        var img = new Image();
        //reader.result is nothing but the Base64 representation
        img.src = reader.result;
        
        //operate the DOM, clear the div and append the img
        div.innerHTML = '';
        div.appendChild(img);
    }
    //read that file using the reader
    reader.readAsDataURL(imgFile);
});
```

```html
<div id="someDiv" style="min-width: 200px;min-height: 200px; border: 1px solid red">
Paste an image here (using Ctrl + V)

</div>
```

Comment: The question was about writing image to clipboard and handling `copy` event. This response seems to be about `paste` event and reading image from clipboard.

Comment: You don't need to handle that, what you need to handle is that paste event to put that somewhere

Comment: Ooh, It seems you want to invoke the action of `copy image` programitically