# How to copy image and text on clipboard with jquery

Tags: jquery, clipboard

I want to achieve image + text copy to clipboard in single click with jQuery. I am able to achieve text but not able to do with image. Below I am sharing code and JSfiddle link.

[Here is fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/talvinder400/zwbjcehv/2/)

Thanks in advance

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">Copy P1</button>

<p id="p1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg"  id="p1">
```

Comment: This answer is possibly outdated, so I won't close as a duplicate, but have you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40547470/519413)? Also note that receiving copied content is also program-specific, so it's possible your logic to perform the image/text copy functionality is working yet the target application strips the content being pasted.

Comment: Hi McCrossan- Thanks for your reply I checked this solutions [https://stackoverflow.com/a/40547470/519413] but this one is only copying text I want dual functionality in which single click will copy both text and image to clipboard so that can be pasted in any other application.

Comment: It should also copy images using HTML, hence my note about the paste target application filtering the content.