# How to copy an image from a URL to the clipboard using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Good morning, I searched around but I didn't find a working solution to copy an image(png, jpg) from a URL link to the clipboard.
I tried:

```js
const response = await fetch(image1);
const blob = await response.blob();
try {
    navigator.clipboard.write([
        new ClipboardItem({
            'image/jpg': blob
        })
    ]);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

Sorry if it's a dumb question.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to ask could you elaborate, please? have a look at this I think the same kind of question. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33175909/copy-image-to-clipboard)

Comment: @Ameya thank you for the response, but I tried the solution proposed
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59162806 but it doesn't work. The other solutions doesn't seem to be what I need. To explain it better, I want to copy an image I have the link of lets say https://........../image.jpg to the clipboard, so I can paste it in my word in a faster way.